# Creating superuser using POST request Django rest framework 3.5

Tags: post, django-rest-framework, superuser

Hey i have one question about creating superuser with djangorestframework.

If i want to create superuser with console i'll write:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

But now i want to create superuser with POST request using DRF 3.5

How should i do that if i'm using Android as a client for example?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a view and serializer around the user that include the is_admin flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    
def save_users(request):
        username = request.GET.get('username')
        email = request.GET.get('email')
        password = request.GET.get('password') 
        users = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).